# Regex without order

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I have a list of characters [a,b,c] and I want to write a regular expression such that
any string is accepted if it has all the elements in the character list at-least once and the characters can appear in any order in the string.

Example of accepted strings

> `abc, aabbbc, bbaac, cab`

Example of strings not accepteed

> `aaabb, bab, caa, aacd, deeff`

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use Regex for this?

Comment: `a+b+c+|a+c+b+|c+b+a+|....` :))

Comment: Can the string have all the characters from the list, plus others too? e.g. is 'abcd' valid?

Comment: No not any specific reason. Just out of curiosity want to know if this can be done with regex

Comment: @mikej No there cannot be... so abcd is not accepted

Comment: @arpanchaudhury - For future reference, I believe your post has fallen victim to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In the future, start off with what you ultimately are trying to accomplish and then lead into an approach you are considering (but the leave the door open for other solutions).

Comment: @devnull - That's a bit snarky. Developers have a habit of reaching for the most intuitive tool. If we all spent our days second-guessing every intuitive decision, we'd never get anything done. Regex is the intuitive tool for matching text, not for developing kernels. That said, the OP has clearly learned that a less intuitive tool is better suited for this particular task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Sets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)** are *much* more suited for this purpose than regular expressions. What you're really trying to do is find out if **(a, b, c)** is a valid subset of your various strings. Here's an example of how to do that in Ruby:

```
> require "set"
 => true 
> reference = Set.new("abc".split(""))
 => #<Set: {"a", "b", "c"}> 
> test1 = Set.new("aabbbc".split(""))
 => #<Set: {"a", "b", "c"}> 
> test2 = Set.new("caa".split(""))
 => #<Set: {"c", "a"}> 
> reference.subset? test1
 => true 
> reference.subset? test2
 => false
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider this before reading on: regexes are [not always the best way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) to solve a problem. If you are considering a regex but it's not obvious or easy to proceed, you may want to stop and consider if there is an easy non-regex solution handy.

I don't know what your specific situation is or why you think you need regex, so I'll assume you already know the above and answer your question as-is.

---

Based on the documentation, I beleive that Ruby supports positive lookaheads (also known as zero-width assertions). Being primarily a .NET programmer, I don't know Ruby well enough to say whether or not it supports non-fixed-length lookaheads (it's not found in all regex flavors), but if it does then you can easily apply three different lookaheads at the beginning of your expression to find each of the patterns or characters you need:

```regex
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c).*
```

This will fail if any one of the lookaheads does not pass. This approach is potentially extremely powerful because you can have complex sub expressions in your lookahead. For example:

```regex
^(?=.*a[bc]{2})(?=.*-\d)(?=.*#.{3}%).*
```

will test that the input contains an <kbd>a</kbd> follwed by two characters which are each either a <kbd>b</kbd> or a <kbd>c</kbd>, a <kbd>-</kbd> followed by any digit and a <kbd>#</kbd> followed by any three characters followed by a <kbd>%</kbd>, in any particular order. So the following strings would pass:

```
#acb%-9
#-22%abb
```

This kind of complex pattern matching is difficult to succinctly duplicate.

---

To address this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900788/regex-without-order/18900912?noredirect=1#comment27899734_18900788):

> No there cannot be... so abcd is not accepted

You can use a negative lookahead to ensure that characters *other* than the desired characters are not present in the input:

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?!.*[^abc]).*
```

(As [noted by Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900788/regex-without-order/18900912?noredirect=1#comment27900045_18900912), the `.*` at the end is not necessary... I probably should have mentioned that. It's just there in case you actually want to select the text)

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: Tags say RUBY, not IronRuby

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Yeah... with three close votes, I needed to post something...

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - I've added an addendum... regex tag downvoters sure are trigger happy. :)

Comment: You guys are harsh. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html Ruby 2 has lookaheads.  NB you don't need the anchor nor the `.*` at the end.

Comment: @Gene - I'm assuming that the OP wants to actually return the string, but yes, it's optional.

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 - actually, my trigger was .Net not being relevant to a question with "Ruby" tag. I mentioned IronRuby, as it is an implementation of Ruby for CLR, but, well, except for that, you cannot directly use .Net's regex engine in Ruby.. it have nothing against the completely relevant lookahead/behinds, just the obvious platform mismatch. I mean, really, the **syntax** can differ really much between engines ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def acceptable? s
  s =~ /(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)/
end

acceptable? 'abc'     # => 0
acceptable? 'aabbbc'  # => 0
acceptable? 'bbaac'   # => 0
acceptable? 'cab'     # => 0
acceptable? 'aaabb'   # => nil
acceptable? 'bab'     # => nil
acceptable? 'caa'     # => nil
acceptable? 'aacd'    # => nil
acceptable? 'deeff'   # => nil
acceptable? 'abcd'    # => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex that matches only the defined characters could be this:

```
(?=[bc]*a)(?=[ac]*b)(?=[ab]*c)[abc]*
```

Comment: Huh... interesting. Except that it will still match `abcd` which [it should *not* do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900788/regex-without-order#comment27899734_18900788).